# How edit this code, to generate every post as separated div? WP

Tags: wordpress

How edit this code, to generate every post as separated div? 
Or it is better way to manage displaying another posts from category?

```
<?php
if ( is_single() ) {
  $categories = get_the_category();
  if ($categories) {
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
      // echo "<pre>"; print_r($category); echo "</pre>";
      $cat = $category->cat_ID;
      $args=array(
        'cat' => $cat,
        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
        'posts_per_page'=>-1,
        'caller_get_posts'=>1
      );
      $my_query = null;
      $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
      if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<h2>Inne wpisy z tej kategorii: '. $category->category_description . '</h2>';
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
          <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Przejdź do <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a></p>
          <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' ); ?> 
       <?php the_excerpt('10');
        endwhile;
      } //if ($my_query)
     } //foreach ($categories
  } //if ($categories)
  wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
} //if (is_single())
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `<div>` just before the `<p>` tag and closing the div just after the `<?php the_excerpt('10');?>` should achieve this.

```
<?php
if ( is_single() ) {
  $categories = get_the_category();
  if ($categories) {
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
      // echo "<pre>"; print_r($category); echo "</pre>";
      $cat = $category->cat_ID;
      $args=array(
        'cat' => $cat,
        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
        'posts_per_page'=>-1,
        'caller_get_posts'=>1
      );
      $my_query = null;
      $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
      if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<h2>Inne wpisy z tej kategorii: '. $category->category_description . '</h2>';
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
          <div>
          <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Przejdź do <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a></p>
          <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' ); ?> 
       <?php the_excerpt('10');?>
           </div>
       <?php
        endwhile;
      } //if ($my_query)
     } //foreach ($categories
  } //if ($categories)
  wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
} //if (is_single())
?>
```

Comment: No problen, if the answer solved your problem, feel free to mark it as correct so other people who have the same question might know the answer you got

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna print each post / category in a seperate div, then you add  in the ECHO statement included in the foreach loop for example :

```
ECHO "<div> <PRE>"; ..... ECHO "</div>"
```

I hope it will help...Good day